# Symfony with nginx not serving .js and .css files

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

Hey I'm trying to deploy my first app using symfony, docker and nginx. For now I only try to run my docker container locally, but when I open index.php it says my `*.css` and `*.js` files are not found and I get 404 error. Also index.php is working because when I change default symfony index.php to `echo "something"` it works. I used webpack encore to build my js and css files,

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
services:

  # nginx
  web: 
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  app:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/vendor
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine



RUN apk update
RUN apk add vim


# install php with pgsql
RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
    postgresql-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1


# get composer using multi-stage build
COPY --from=composer:2.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY ./composer.* ./

# install bundles from composer.json with options for deployment
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts --no-progress --no-interaction

# copy application files to default directory
COPY . .

# run composer dump-autload 
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

default.conf for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }
}
```

files structure

```
app
│   composer.json
│   composer.lock
│   docker-compose.prod.yml
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   webpack.config.js
│   
├───nginx
│   └───conf.d
│           default.conf
├───php
│       Dockerfile
│       
├───public
│   │   .htaccess
│   │   index.php
│   │   
│   └───build
│           500.c01022e5.js
│           app.90dc63d1.js
│           app.c6fd8b2d.css
│           entrypoints.json
│           manifest.json
│           runtime.61b1725c.js
```

Those are errors that I get when I open `localhost:80`

```
GET http://localhost/build/runtime.61b1725c.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/build/app.c6fd8b2d.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/build/app.90dc63d1.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/build/500.c01022e5.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `- .:/var/www/html` in your web volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mount `./public` directory into the nginx container:

```
services:

  # nginx
  web: 
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./public:/var/www/html/public

  app:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/vendor
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Comment: It worked thank you a lot. It is logical, but it's my first time with docker+nginx so I'm still learning. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't mention it <3